# Lookbehind works in Chrome, but breaks in Safari: Invalid regular expression invalid group

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Works in Chrome, but breaks in Safari: Invalid regular expression: invalid group specifier name

```
/^(?=.{1,50}$)(?![_.-])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[a-z0-9._-]+(?<![_.-])$/
```

Answer (score 3):

Guess the lookbehind is not supported by Safari JS regex. Good news, it's not needed here.

```
^(?![_.-])(?!.*[_.-]{2})[a-z\d._-]{0,49}[a-z\d]$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Hv7hG0/1)

Just another (self explaining) way to write the pattern without the lookbehind at the end.

Comment: I have been lazy and used your example data for the regex101 demo :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a singe lookahead assertion for the length, and then start and end the match with a char a-z0-9 not allowing consecutive matches for `[._-]`

```
^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-z\d]+(?:[._-][a-z\d]+)*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=.{1,50}$)` Positive lookahead, assert 50 chars till the end of string
- `[a-z\d]+` Match 1+ chars a-z0-9
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[._-][a-z\d]+` Match one of `.` _ -` and 1+ chars of a-z0-9
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oWuP4r/1)

Comment: Haha, yea that's fine 4th bird! :) Very nice, short and efficient one. If we start the competition for the most compact and allow `\d` for `[0-9]` yours could even be [compressed further](https://regex101.com/r/qKRNGf/1).

Comment: @bobblebubble But of course :-) No competitions here (I would definitely loose :-)), just fun and puzzling challenges.

Comment: :) Yes, I share that attitude, but you would certainly not loose! However I like making pattern short and efficient whenever possible and this "unrolled" is really nice.